# Sorting by unanswered breaks when changing pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Search on a tag, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d
2. At the top of the page, click "unanswered" in the list of links under the tag description
3. Notice that there are no posts with an accepted answer
4. Scroll down the bottom of the page and click "next" in the page navigation
5. Notice that there are posts with an accepted answer

Note: The URLs in steps 3 and 5 are the same, except for the `page` variable in the latter. I don't think clicking these links directly will load the desired configuration, i.e. the filter isn't applied; you have to follow the steps to see the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d?filter=need-answers&sort=votes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d?filter=need-answers&sort=votes&page=2

Comment: _"I don't think clicking these links directly will load the desired configuration, i.e. the filter isn't applied;"_ Clicking the second of those links did take me to a list with the issue, by the way. I was able to repro this myself, and an added note: I even tried switching the filter, on page 2, to "no answer" and back- "no answer" seemed to work, and switching back to "needs answer" kept the same issue from going to page two in the first place.

Comment: Actually, upon playing with this a little more, I can't get "needs answer" to work period unless I click the link you mention in the tag description. I _think_ that particular issue, needs answer not working period, was mentioned elsewhere. This could just be another part of that bug.

Comment: Thanks for verifying, @Kendra!  Note that clicking either link at the bottom of the question actually strips out the filter URL variable when the page loads up. However, I don't see "no answer" as an option.

Comment: By "no answer" I mean in the _actual_ filter selection. When that page is loaded that way, it automatically sets the filter to "needs answer" as that is the matching filter for "unanswered." And odd- The first time I opened one of the two links at the bottom, it _kept_ the filter. Now it's not doing that...

Comment: Clicking on "unanswered" in the tag description works (just for page 1 of that tag's questions), but clicking "need answers" in the filter dropdown does nothing.

Comment: Wow, this is a mess. I didn't expect the "unanswered" link, whose link target is "sort=unanswered" to actually resolve to a *filter* URL. After all, "unanswered" means "has no answers" whereas "needs answers" means "doesn't have an accepted answer". Why use two different names? And indeed, this is much like my own [question about "most linked"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309512/4125191), where the link URL is strange, but does the job, and the actual sort is dead.

Comment: Another note: in the previous "new nav", the "need answers" option was good because it presented questions that were relatively recent. This "unanswered" brings up old unanswered questions that have lots of votes, which is not actually helpful. If it wasn't answered since 2014 despite all those votes, it's unlikely to be answerable now.

Comment: Good points. Yeah, for some reason, clicking "unanswered" adds a sort by votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).