# Sorting by most linked is ineffective

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

I click on the site logo, get to the home page. Click on the Java tag. Then, from the sort menu on the right, I choose "most linked". The result:

[image: Screen shot of home page after selecting a tag and sorting]

The sort button obediently put "?sort=linked" in the location bar, but these are not the <strike>droids</strike> questions I'm looking for.

Start afresh. Go to the home page. Click on Java. Now click on the little "most linked" link below the tag wiki excerpt. I get this:

[image: Screen shot of home page after selecting a tag and clicking "most linked"]

Now, this is the correct query. The URL, you'll note, is the same. Observations:

- When using the second option (clicking on the "most linked" link), it temporarily goes through to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/?sort=frequent (frequent? why?), and then is magically redirected - to the same URL as the first option. But it produces the correct results.
- Using the actual URL (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=linked) directly in any way (refreshing the page, pasting it into the location bar, adding the query manually at the end) - does nothing at all. In fact, it redirects immediately to the base URL without the query, and shows just the default tag page.

Browser information: Firefox 41.0.2, Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: I don't think it's just "most linked" that has this issue- Unanswered is much the same! (See the comments [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309481/sorting-by-unanswered-breaks-when-changing-pages) for instance.) It's odd that both of those don't work.

Comment: Oh, this is interesting... Looks like a bug in the URL rewriting script: it thinks the option is called "linked", but it is still called "frequent". Note that if you open the "frequent" link and you're not logged in, you don't redirect and get the correct results no matter how many times you refresh.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).