# Cannot view second page of unanswered questions

Tags: bug, user-interface, mobile-web, question-lists

When I browse on mobile (Android, Chrome) and select "Unanswered" at the top of a questions list, the page loads as expected, but the selected tab is listed as "Votes".

All the pagination links at the bottom of the page include `sort=votes`, so I can't view the second/third/etc. page of unanswered questions.

Is this a regression of [Sorting by unanswered breaks when changing pages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309481/), or was it perhaps never fixed on the mobile version of the site?

Chrome 77.0.3865.116
Android 8.1.0

[Imgur: video of reproduction](https://i.imgur.com/44JtOAT.mp4)

Comment: Can be reproduced on desktop as well if you visit the [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered) and click the "Mobile" link in the footer.