# Filtering for unanswered questions after applying a custom filter breaks when changing pages

Tags: bug

On the stackoverflow and the StackOverflow Meta site I encountered a bug while searching for tags by using a custom filter: Filtering for unanswered questions after applying a custom filter breaks when changing pages. This seems similar to the behavior reported in  [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309481/sorting-by-unanswered-breaks-when-changing-pages) which is reported to be fixed by now.

## Steps to reproduce:

1. At the [tags page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) create a custom filter (I search for the tag "bug").
2. Click on the newly created filter, click on "Filter" in order to further customize it, select "no answer" and "apply filter".

Now, the results update as expected.

3. Then go to the second page. Now, the amount of found pages increases, as the filter "no answer" is not applied anymore; questions turn up which are already answered.

I suspect that additional constraints on the filter (in this case, also filtering for unanswered questions) are lost when changing pages. The bug does not seem to occur when not making use of a custom filter.

#### Browser on which I recreated this issue:

- Qutebrowser v1.10.1
- Firefox 74.0
- Chromium 80.0.3987.149

The bug occurs independent of the selected tag. The important part is that you need to **use a previously saved custom filter** (which are listed in the right panel, as described in step one in the *steps to reproduce* section).
[Video where I record the steps to reproduce and the result](https://github.com/juliusHuelsmann/stuff/blob/master/bug-2020-03-25_11.15.10.mp4).

Comment: I cannot recreate it. Is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug?sort=newest&filters=noanswers&page=2&pagesize=50) the filter you're using? I don't see any questions with answers on the second page.

Comment: @VLAZ you need to create a custom filter, and use that filter. If you are only using for a tag, the problem does not occur. I will attach a video where I record the steps mentioned above in the quesiton.

Comment: This [*is* a custom filter](https://i.imgur.com/Wi7gp2S.png) and [here are the results I see on page 2](https://i.imgur.com/k5sfg4p.png) when I use it

Comment: OK, you left out an super important important part: SAVE THE FILTER! Also, afterwards load the filter and modify it. Yes, I can reproduce it now. I can also see the issue - when you change the filter, the URL contains the filter ID, as well as whether it was changed. When you go to the next page, you *lose* the `edited=true` from the URL and presumably the site just re-loads the saved filter.